# WPF datagrid control throwing exception

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have installed Feb 2010 wpf toolkit and make a refference of wpfttoolkit.dll in my project. i have following xmlns

```
<Window x:Class="NodeXL_Graph_Drawer.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
  Title="NodeXL Graph" Height="300" Width="300" xmlns:my="clr-         namespace:Smrf.NodeXL.Visualization.Wpf;assembly=Smrf.NodeXL.Control.Wpf" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>

    <toolkit:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid1" ></toolkit:DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

but when window loads it throws following exception there is no source code available for this location with following stack information

```
   ---         C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataGrid\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\Primitives\DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.cs 
  00000000  push        ebp  
  00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
  00000003  sub         esp,0Ch 
  00000006  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],ecx 
  00000009  cmp         dword ptr ds:[03E75CA0h],0 
  00000010  je          00000017 
  00000012  call        76B9D779 
  00000017  xor         edx,edx 
  00000019  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],edx 
  0000001c  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
  0000001f  call        526C6518 
  00000024  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax 
  00000027  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
  0000002a  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax 
  0000002d  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
  00000030  cmp         dword ptr [eax+0000011Ch],0 
  00000037  je          0000003C 
  00000039  inc         dword ptr [ebp-4] 
  0000003c  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
  0000003f  cmp         dword ptr [eax+00000118h],0 
  00000046  je          0000004B 
  00000048  inc         dword ptr [ebp-4] 
  0000004b  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4] 
  0000004e  mov         esp,ebp 
  00000050  pop         ebp  
  00000051  ret
```

Comment: Are you manipulating your Toolkits DataGrid in code-behind (e.g. in the Window_Loaded EventHandler)? If thats the case, please post this part also. ;)

Comment: No i m doing nothing in .cs part even not using any member or properties of datagrid1

Comment: Strange...maybe your toolkit is broken? I copied your code and didnt get an error. Try to re-install it.

Comment: Reinstallation the kit make datagrid working perfectly .